# Xpath is not working in selenium

Tags: angularjs, angular, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automate an `Angular 2.0 application.`

HTML Code:

```
<input _hello="" class="myclass" formcontrolname="phoneCtrl" required="" sdcleave="" sdmutekeys="[0-9]" type="text" placeholder="Phone number">
```

When I try to locate above element using `xpath` locator, it gives me below mentioned error.

Tried Code:

```
//input[@class='myclass'][0]
```

> Error:no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":"//input[@class='myclass'][0]"}(..)

Can anyone help me on this issue?

Comment: Phone number field is-
<input _hello="" class="myclass" formcontrolname="phoneCtrl" required="" sdcleave="" sdmutekeys="[0-9]" type="text" placeholder="Phone number">

Comment: Try: `.//input[@placeholder='Phone number']`

Comment: please provide html code snipper

Comment: it worked.
.//input[@placeholder='Phone number']

Comment: Can you tell me why you added . at start ?

Comment: The `.` really shouldn't be at the start. The `.` means start with the current element as the context. It's for when you have an existing element and you want to search under it in the DOM but that's not happening in this case.

Comment: I have a habit of using `.`. I agree with JeffC

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your DOM is not ready yet when Webdriver tries to locate element.
Add this code in a `util.js` file :

**util.js**

```
'use strict';

/**
 * Navigate to an url and wait some seconds
 * @param {string} path The path
 * @param {seconds} [seconds] The number of seconds to wait for
 * @returns {Promise}
 * @see waitSomeSeconds
 */
function navigateAndWait(path, seconds) {
  return browser.get(path)
    .then(function () {
      return waitSomeSeconds(seconds);
    });
}

/**
 * Wait some seconds (default is 3)
 * @param {int} [seconds]
 * @returns {Promise}
 */
function waitSomeSeconds(seconds) {
  return browser.sleep((seconds || 3) * 1000);
}

module.exports = {
  navigateAndWait: navigateAndWait,
  waitSomeSeconds: waitSomeSeconds
}
```

**homepage.spec.js**

```
'use strict';

var util = require('./util');

describe('Homepage test suite', function () {

  it('should navigate to homepage', function() {
    return util.navigateAndWait('/homepage');
  });

  it('should display title with correct data', function() {
    expect(element(by.css('h1')).getText()).toBe('Welcome');
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off using a CSS selector for something like this. XPath is not as widely supported and the performance is not as good as CSS selectors.

This should work

```
By.cssSelector("input[placeholder='Phone number']");
```

You should spend some time learning about CSS selectors. They are very powerful locators and, in my experience, can be used in 99% of locators successfully.

[CSS Selector Reference](https://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#selectors)

[CSS Selector Tips](https://saucelabs.com/resources/articles/selenium-tips-css-selectors)

Answer (score 0):

Xpath indexes start with **1** and not **0** and that's the reason webdriver is throwing an error.

Correct XPath Would be

```
//input[@class='myclass'][1]
```

For example for the following XPath to find google search box won't give you any Element.

```
//*[@id='lst-ib'][0]
```

but following would just work fine

```
//*[@id='lst-ib'][1]
```

Use the tool like https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/firebug/ and https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/firepath/ to check if you XPath is valid or not.

Comment: hey looks need to update xpath as //input[@class='myclass'][1] above

Comment: @muraliselenium thanks, I was in hurry I posted this answer and so made couple of mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

Try this way using `xpath locator`

**Explanation:** Use `placeholder` attribute of `<input>` tag.

```
//input[@placeholder='Phone number']
```

In `java` You can do this way.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@placeholder='Phone number']")).sendKeys("1234567890");
```

Comment: Please Mark this answer as `Accepted` if it's resolved your issue.